# Block Level Elements inside Inline elements

Tags: html, css, xhtml, standards

The W3C Validator tells me I can't put block-level elements inside inline elements. Makes sense...

but what if I'm using CSS to change that block-level element into an inline element?

And what if I'm using CSS to convert an inline element into a block-level element (when inside another inline element)?

The Validator doesn't pick up on this obviously, but is it wrong?

(I'm not actually doing this, I'm just wondering about best-practice)

Answer (score 13):

An element defined as a block element in the HTML specification is not the same as a element defined as `display: block;` in CSS.

With this I mean: Even if you say `<p style="display: inline;">Lorem...</p>`. The `<p>` will still be a block element in the eyes of HTML.

HTML, CSS and JavaScript if used right is said to have [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) toward each other and that one should not be dependent of another and that the absence of one should not make the others (or the system as whole) fail.

Comment: This generation, they're becoming dependent to each other.

Comment: @JovylleBermudez How so? In what way? Do you have an example?

Comment: After few months, I'm not sure not why I said that, did the answer changed?
But one thing is for sure, the block element will cause a line break to the inline element where it is inside.

Answer (score 5):

An element that is inline elements should not contain block elements. Block elements can contain block and/or inline elements while inline elements can only contain other inline (including `inline-block`, such as `<img>`) elements.

You can of course do it anyways, since the graphical representation will be pretty consistent across browsers. It's still not something I'd recommend though, and can't really think of a reason to do it either.

Comment: An `<a>` (inline element) is quite often seen containing a `<div>` (block element).