# Can inline elements contain block elements?

Tags: html

Can an inline element contain a block element for instance: can a list have a paragraph?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Block Level Elements inside Inline elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714121/block-level-elements-inside-inline-elements)

Comment: Nope. 

To answer your second question, a list is not an inline element. A list can contain P or DIV tags or whatever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that LI and P are both block level ...

It's never valid to do so, but in behavioural terms, **sometimes** you can nest a block level element inside a inline level one, but it depends on the browser parser.

For example, in FireFox 3.x, with this markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<i>
   foo
   <div>bar</div>
   baz
</i>
```

will display foo, bar, and baz all in italics.

But this markup, replacing the inline element `<i>` with inline element `<var>` (which also has italics as its default rendering)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<var>
   foo
   <div>bar</div>
   baz
</var>
```

will only display foo in italics.

[JSFiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/TdBEV/)

Other browsers do not behave the same. Which is one reason why you should stick to using valid markup.

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but HTML5 does allow you to wrap <a> tags around just about anything, include block level elements.

Comment: @user1334007 - indeed, providing the wrapped elements would be valid if they were children of the `<a>` element's parent and the `<a>` element is a valid descendant of its ancestors. But on the other hand, there's no such thing as either a block element or an inline element in HTML5. `<a>` is *phrasing element*. Block and inline were concepts of HTML 4, and remain concepts in CSS, which has its own rules about what happens when inline elements contain block elements, but is not concerned with the validity of HTML content models.

Answer (score 2):

It can, but it won't pass validation.  There are ways round it that have been thoroughly discussed here:
[Is it wrong to change a block element to inline with CSS if it contains another block element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another-b)

Answer (score 0):

It's incorrect markup to use a block element within an inline one. It may still render if the browser and Doctype are lenient, but it's not valid.

You can usee CSS, however, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another-b).

Answer (score 0):

If you want block elements to behave like inline elements, set the display property to `inline-block`. If you need to support IE 7 or 6, for the same elements in your IE stylesheet, add these two rules: `zoom:1; display:inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Inline element can't contain block element and  block element can contain all kind of. <li> , that you've mentioned, is not an inline element it's a block element as <p> ,  so both can contain each others

Answer (score 0):

> block-level elements cannot descend from inline-level elements

Eric Meyer book "CSS The dfinitive Guid" page 9

Answer (score -5):

```
<li> & <p> both are inline elements. so you can use <p> inside <li>
```

Comment: `p` elements are block elements, not inline. However, they can only contain inline elements.

Comment: LIs are not inline. Neither are P tags. LIs allow block level content in them : http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html. Please update your answer.

Comment: Sorry i got confused. Pardon me.. Thanks for classifications.