# display:flex in a child element breaks the display:inline of the parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Say I've got three inline elements that contain spans, something of the type of

```
<div class="my-inline-element">
    <span >Item1</span>
</div>

<div class="my-inline-element">
    <span >Item2</span>
</div>  

<div class="my-inline-element">
    <span >Item3</span>
</div>
```

`.my-inline-element` style has `display:inline;`:

```
.my-inline-element{
  border:2px solid red;
  display:inline;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

Everything works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/dbbd0zLa/1/)

[image: expected styling]

The problem happens when I want to make the span inside `display:flex;`...

```
.my-inline-element span {
  display: flex;
}
```

Why does it break the parent (`my-inline-element`) inline display?
(https://jsfiddle.net/9qdphh61/1/)

[image: broken inline style]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution:

Use `display: inline-flex` instead of `display: flex`.

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9qdphh61/2/)

Or, as pointed out in the comments by @LarsW, make the parent `display: inline-block` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9qdphh61/3/)).

---

#### Explanation

When you apply `display: flex` to an element, this gives the element [block-level-like properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers). Hence, you're putting a block-level element inside an inline element.

First, this is invalid HTML:

> [**7.5.3 Block-level and inline
>   elements**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)
>
> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other
>   block-level elements. ***Generally, inline elements may contain only data
>   and other inline elements.*** Inherent in this structural distinction is
>   the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline
>   elements.
>
> *<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>*

Second, this causes the inline element to "break around" the block-level box.

> [**9.2.1.1. Anonymous block
>   boxes**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level)
>
> When an inline box contains an in-flow block-level box, the inline box
>   (and its inline ancestors within the same line box) are broken around
>   the block-level box (and any block-level siblings that are consecutive
>   or separated only by collapsible whitespace and/or out-of-flow
>   elements), splitting the inline box into two boxes (even if either
>   side is empty), one on each side of the block-level box(es). The line
>   boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in anonymous
>   block boxes, and the block-level box becomes a sibling of those
>   anonymous boxes. When such an inline box is affected by relative
>   positioning, any resulting translation also affects the block-level
>   box contained in the inline box.

Also see these posts:

- [Is it wrong to change a block element to inline with CSS if it contains another block element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/746531/3597276)
- [Block Level Elements inside Inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1714121/3597276)

Comment: Thank you for the references to the specs and the elaborated answer that explain exactly why this was happening