# css - block elements ignoring line-height

Tags: html, css

**Edit:** I need to move on for now, so I've temporarily added `style="line-height:50px` to the `span` element of the first `li` item (`nav-item--home`).  If anyone sees the difference between the two sites, which makes the first `<a>` element ignore its `line-height`, please let me know.

I'm trying to implement the same styling from the top navigation bar on the site:

https://acrobotic.com

on the site:

http://learn.acrobotic.com

As you can see, the first element inside the `<ul>` doesn't align vertically with the rest. The element consists of:

```
<li class="nav-item nav-item--home level0 level-top active">
  <a class="level-top" href="http://learn.acrobotic.com/">
    <span class="ic ic-home"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

By comparing the two I notice that the `<span>` element has the correct size (30x16). However, the `<a>` element containing it has an incorrect height of 16px (54x16) whereby it should be 50px. Its height should be set by the `line-height` property provided it's a block element.

For debugging purpose using the console in Developer Tools I check the CSS by:

```
jQuery('.ic-home').parent().css('display')
"block"

jQuery('.ic-home').parent().css('line-height')
"50px"
```

Both properties seem to be set correctly, however, as the title mentions the block element is ignoring the `line-height` property.  If you can shine a light into this problem I'd be grateful as it's been a couple of days of banging my head against this wall.

Comment: No, I'm using JavaScript to debug the CSS.  I'll clarify it on the post.

Comment: An inline element (like an `a` tag) should not contain a block element (even a `span` tag marked as `display: block`), which might explain the weird behavior.  Try putting the line-height on the `li`?

Comment: More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714121/block-level-elements-inside-inline-elements

Comment: @ErtySeidohl That doesn't really explain why the https://acrobotic.com/ works, they have the exact same code (as far as I can tell) besides the fonts. Also adding the line-height doesn't work.

Comment: Ever figure this out?  Having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see in css by development tools this:
.menu-trigger, .nav-regular .nav-item.level0 > a and in the "a" tag of the icon is set to 50px instead in the others "li a" tag is set to 20px. if you change it it clears.

Comment: As far as I can tell all of the `<a>`'s line-heights are set by the CSS rule `.menu-trigger, .nav-regular .nav-item.level0 > a` to `50px`.